# Pandas conditional check depending on row and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following thresholds:

```
for a_x: red=10 blue=5
for a_y: red=50 blue=15
for b_x: red=8  blue=4
for b_y: red=40 blue=10
```

And this is the dataframe that I have:

```
type  x1   x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  z
a     1    3   5   11  13  9   qaz
a     2    7   9   23  67  35  qeq
a     7    9   13  36  24  8   rfc
b     10   3   5   51  19  10  qwe
b     5    4   2   21  12  11  erg
b     1    2   3   9   7   8   gbt
```

Now for rows with type=a, I want to use a_x threshold for any column containing x in the column name and a_y threshold columns containing y.

Similarly, for rows with type=b, I want to use b_x thresholds for columns containing x, while b_y thresholds for columns containing y.

Ultimately, I want to create two new dataframes, red and blue, containing all the rows where red thresholds was breached (breached is when value >= threshold) and only blue threshold was breached (therefore, if red threshold is breached then no need to check for blue threshold, as it will only be part of red and not blue).

So, finally we will have the following dataframes:

red:

```
type  x1   x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  z
a     2    7   9   23  67  35  qeq
a     7    9   13  36  24  8   rfc
b     10   3   5   51  19  10  qwe
```

blue:

```
type  x1   x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  z
a     1    3   5   11  13  9   qaz
b     5    4   2   21  12  11  erg
```

as,

```
type  x1   x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  z
a     1    3   5   11  13  9   qaz  -> x3 breaches blue
a     2    7   9   23  67  35  qeq  -> y2 breaches red
a     7    9   13  36  24  8   rfc  -> x3 breaches red
b     10   3   5   51  19  10  qwe  -> x1, y1 breaches red
b     5    4   2   21  12  11  erg  -> x1, x2, y1, y2, y3 breaches blue
b     1    2   3   9   7   8   gbt  -> no breach
```

Now, obviously, I can just iterate over all the rows and columns and check for threshold breach, but there must be a better way of doing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I create your conditions to nested dictionary:

```
d = {'a_x': {'red':10, 'blue':5},
     'a_y': {'red':50, 'blue':15},
     'b_x': {'red':8, 'blue':4},
     'b_y': {'red':40, 'blue':10}}
```

Better format is separate `red` and `blue` values to outer dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict


d1 = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in d.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
      d1[k1][k] = v1

print (d1)
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'red': {'a_x': 10, 'a_y': 50, 'b_x': 8, 'b_y': 40}, 
                             'blue': {'a_x': 5, 'a_y': 15, 'b_x': 4, 'b_y': 10}})
```

Then loop by each dict and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with splitted `k` values by `_`:

```
red = [df.loc[df['type'].eq(k.split('_')[0]), 
            df.columns.str.startswith(k.split('_')[1])] >= v for k, v in d1['red'].items()]
```

Then join masks together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and test if at least one row match by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
mask_red = pd.concat(red).any(level=0).any(axis=1)
# print (mask_red)


blue = [df.loc[df['type'].eq(k.split('_')[0]), 
           df.columns.str.startswith(k.split('_')[1])] >= v for k, v in d1['blue'].items()]

mask_blue = pd.concat(blue).any(level=0).any(axis=1)
# print (mask_blue)
```

Last filter match red values:

```
df1 = df[mask_red]
print (df1)
  type  x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3    z
1    a   2   7   9  23  67  35  qeq
2    a   7   9  13  36  24   8  rfc
3    b  10   3   5  51  19  10  qwe
```

And blue values with excluded already used in red DataFrame:

```
df2 = df[mask_blue & ~mask_red]
print (df2)
  type  x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3    z
0    a   1   3   5  11  13   9  qaz
4    b   5   4   2  21  12  11  erg
```

For avoid repeating code is possible use dictionary comprehension for dictionary of masks:

```
d = {'a_x': {'red':10, 'blue':5},
     'a_y': {'red':50, 'blue':15},
     'b_x': {'red':8, 'blue':4},
     'b_y': {'red':40, 'blue':10}}


d1 = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in d.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
      d1[k1][k] = v1

print (d1)
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'red': {'a_x': 10, 'a_y': 50, 'b_x': 8, 'b_y': 40}, 
                             'blue': {'a_x': 5, 'a_y': 15, 'b_x': 4, 'b_y': 10}})
```

---

```
masks = {k1: pd.concat([df.loc[df['type'].eq(k.split('_')[0]), 
               df.columns.str.startswith(k.split('_')[1])] >= v 
           for k, v in v1.items()]).any(level=0).any(axis=1)
           for k1, v1 in d1.items()}

print (masks)
{'red': 0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool, 'blue': 0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool}
```

---

```
df1 = df[masks['red']]
print (df1)
  type  x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3    z
1    a   2   7   9  23  67  35  qeq
2    a   7   9  13  36  24   8  rfc
3    b  10   3   5  51  19  10  qwe

df2 = df[masks['blue'] & ~masks['red']]
print (df2)
  type  x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3    z
0    a   1   3   5  11  13   9  qaz
4    b   5   4   2  21  12  11  erg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare some conditional filters such as:

```
 a_red_filter = (df[type] == 'a') & (df[['x1','x2','x3']] < [10]*3) &
(df[['y1','y2','y3']]<[50]*3)

 b_red_filter = (df[type] == 'b') & (df[['x1','x2','x3']] < [8]*3) &
(df[['y1','y2','y3']] <[40]*3)
```

and if you execute the command:

```
df[a_red_filter | b_red_filter]
```

you will have the DataFrame for red points hence:

```
type  x1   x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  z
a     2    7   9   23  67  35  qeq
a     7    9   13  36  24  8   rfc
b     10   3   5   51  19  10  qwe
```

obviously it's the same for blue

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Probably because where i wrote "threshold_x
    condition" you need to fill it with the condition you would like to put as threshold. Unluckily i couldn't quite understand the conditions and  I put this placeholder.

Comment: Now I replaced the placeholders with the actual running code.

Comment: hmmm, I think treshold are for avoid manually type code like your answer... If there are 20 colors? so 40 times repeated code? What if x columns is from `x1` to `x100` ?

Comment: For the column selection you can always do df[df.columns[1:101], while for the color i hardcoded it because the point is to show the possibility of conditional selection in Pandas, of course you can select it accordingly to the data structure of the thresholds, which wasn't given. So i guess it's impossible to find an automated way to get the thresholds with this informations. If you have any suggestions it's higly welcome

Comment: Yop, agree. Working for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, u can read this better than the previous mess I posted

```
#reshape table and create column of just the alphabets
M = (df.melt(['type','z'])
     .assign(letters=lambda x: x.variable.str[0])
     )

red_a = M.query('type=="a" and ((letters=="x" and value >=10) or (letters=="y" and value >=50))')
red_b = M.query('type=="b" and ((letters=="x" and value >=8) or (letters=="y" and value >=40))')
blue_a = M.query('type=="a" and ((letters=="x" and value >=5) or (letters=="y" and value >=15))')
blue_b = M.query('type=="b" and ((letters=="x" and value >=4) or (letters=="y" and value >=10))')

red_only = (pd.concat([red_a,red_b])
            .filter(['type','z'])
            .drop_duplicates('z')
           )

red_only_z = red_only["z"].tolist()

blue_only = (pd.concat([blue_a,blue_b])
             .filter(['type','z'])
              #if row already belongs in red, filter it out
             .query('z != @red_only_z')
             .drop_duplicates('z')
             )
#extract tables from the original dataframe
cond_red = df['z'].isin(red_only_z) & (df['type'].isin(red_only['type']))
cond_blue = df['z'].isin(blue_only['z']) & (df['type'].isin(blue_only['type']))
red_table = df.loc[cond_red]
blue_table = df.loc[cond_blue]

print(blues)    
    type    x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  z
0   a       1   3   5   11  13  9   qaz
4   b       5   4   2   21  12  11  erg

print(reds)
    type    x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3  z
1   a       2   7   9   23  67  35  qeq
2   a       7   9   13  36  24  8   rfc
3   b      10   3   5   51  19  10  qwe
```